# Управление персонажем на Android Unity3D 4.6? (C#)

Tags: android, c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

Здравствуйте.
Делаю игру на Unity3D 4.6.
Сделал игру, на ПК все нормально, управление на клаве работает, но мне надо управление сделать на Android, но я никак не могу. Помогите пожалуйста.
Вот мой скрипт, движение выполняется нажатием кнопки (KeyDown) и отпущением кнопки (KeyUp):

```
void Update(){
    if (movePlayer){
        //прижок
        if (grounded && (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow))) {

            //стрибок
            rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2(0f,jumpForce));
            //Включається анімація стрибка
            anim.SetBool("jump", false);
            //Координати колайдера      
            boxCollider.size = new Vector2(1.6f, 0.48f);
            boxCollider.center = new Vector2(-0.08f, -0.71f);

        }
        //Приседание
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.DownArrow)) {

            //Включається анімація пригинання
            anim.SetBool("leam", true);
            //Координати колайдера
            boxCollider.size = new Vector2(2.0f, 1.5f);
            boxCollider.center = new Vector2(0.23f, -0.1f);

        }

        if (!grounded && (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.UpArrow))) {

            //Координати колайдера      
            boxCollider.size = new Vector2(0.54f, 2.89f);
            boxCollider.center = new Vector2(-0.06f, 0.19f);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.DownArrow)) {

            //Виключається анімація пригинання
            anim.SetBool("leam", false);
            //Координати колайдера
            boxCollider.size = new Vector2(0.54f, 2.89f);
            boxCollider.center = new Vector2(-0.06f, 0.19f);

        }

        //Повернення до початку гри
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
        {
            Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Код демонстрирует управление с клавиатуры ПК, окей; а где собственно попытки сделать управление на Андроиде? Или подразумевается Андроид с клавиатурой?

Comment: Официальное руководство не только вполне подробное, но и даже почти полностью переведено на русский: http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/MobileInput.html

Comment: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/15233 Вот как бы есть бесплатное решение. Однако я бы на вашем месте сам бы подумал как это можно реализовать если вы хотите в будущем заниматься разработкой... Подумать в сторону Canvas , прицепить туда кнопку, написать событие соответствующее нужному вам движению...

Answer (score 1):

1. Создай канвас на экране
2. размести там любой обьект который реагирует на клик пальцем. (должен иметь "Raycast Target" и он должен быть выставлен на "true") -- например Image.
3. ну и на соответствующем ивенте рейкаста вызываешь соответствующий блок кода/метод.

Но это не поможет если нужно делать свайпы. Свайпы делаются по-другому.

Comment: Спасибо, я давно искал ответ на этот вопрос, пока не натолкнулся на эту тему